# Adding a char to every string in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string

For example

```
String temp = "welcome,to,the,world,of,j2ee";
```

converting this to arraylist

```
ArrayList al= new ArrayList(temp.split(","));
```

this comes as content of arraylist as `{"welcome","to","the","world","j2ee"}`

my requirement is adding "^d" at end of every string

for ex `{"welcome^d","to^d","the^d","world^d","j2ee^d"}`

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> al= Arrays.asList((temp.replaceAll(",", "^d,") + "^d").split(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the split, you could add the ^d. For example:

```
String temp = "Welcome,to,the,world,of,j2ee";
ArrayList<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(temp.replaceAll(",", "^d,").split(","));
```

Comment: This will not add `^d` to the last element of the list

Answer (score 0):

String.split does not return an array list, it returns a regular array. If you use a regular array then just concat ^d onto each value.

```
String temp = "welcome,to,the,world,of,j2ee";
    String[] al= temp.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < al.length; i++){
        al[i] += "^d";
    }
    for(String w : al){
    System.out.println(w);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String temp = "welcome,to,the,world,of,j2ee";
    temp = (temp + "^d").replace(",", "^d,");
    List<String> al= Arrays.asList(temp.split(","));
```